# How to add item in redux with dictionary type in react typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-redux, react-typescript

I am using react-redux with typescript. I am importing a JSON file in my redux slice for an initial value. Now, I want to perform a crud operation on a dictionary. I want to add item only in the required key, for that what will be the type structure and how do I perform the operation?

my external JSON contains employee data with respect to the department. department as a key and employees as an array of objects. my structure looks like below:

```
{
  "0": [{...},{...},{...}],
  "1": [{...},{...},{...}],
  "2": [{...},{...},{...}],
}
```

My slice code looks like this:

```
type employeeType = {
    id: number,
    name: string,
    age: number,
    DOB: number
}

type departments = {
    [departmentNo: string]: employeeType[];
}

const initialState:departments = require("./data.json");


export const employeeReducer = (state: departments = initialState, action: any) => {
    switch (action.type){
        case "ADD_EMPLOYEE": {
            return ({})
        }
        default: {
            return state
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think about what information you need in order to make the correct modification to `state`.  Your state is keyed by department number, so in order to add a new employee **you will need to know which department you are adding them to**.  You also need to know all the details of the employee object.  Your `action.payload` might look like this:

```
interface AddEmployeePayload {
    departmentNo: string;
    employee: EmployeeType;
}
```

I highly recommend creating your reducer with [Redux Toolkit](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/) so that you can use a simple `push` operation instead of dealing with [immutable nested updates](https://redux.js.org/usage/structuring-reducers/immutable-update-patterns).

It's up to you how you want to handle cases where the `departmentNo` doesn't match an existing array on your `state` object.  Throw an error?  Create a new array?

```
import { createSlice, PayloadAction } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

const employeeSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'employees',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    addEmployee: (state, action: PayloadAction<AddEmployeePayload>) => {
      // Get the data from our action.
      const { departmentNo, employee } = action.payload;
      // Access the existing array of employees in this department.
      const employeeArray = state[departmentNo];
      if (employeeArray) {
        // Add this employee to the array.
        employeeArray.push(employee);
      } else {
        // Warn about potential invalid ids.
        console.warn(`Unknown department number ${departmentNo}.`);
        // Create a new department array with just this employee in it.
        state[departmentNo] = [employee];
      }
    }
  }
})


export const employeeReducer = employeeSlice.reducer;

// action creator function
export const { addEmployee } = employeeSlice.actions;
```

[Complete Code](https://tsplay.dev/w66eRw)